# Transforming a PNG image in application/x-recordio-protobuf for calling a sagemaker endpoint in C#

Tags: c#, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to do some inferences on a SageMaker endpoint in C# using a `InvokeEndpointRequest` object. My inference body is a PNG or JPEG image. However, SageMaker requires an `application/x-recordio-protobuf` format. How can I convert my image file into this format to be able to use InvokeEndpoint with the above object.

```
InvokeEndpointRequest invokeRequest = new InvokeEndpointRequest
{
  EndpointName = "kmeans-2019-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xxx",
  Body= GetImageFromFile(),
  ContentType= "application/x-recordio-protobuf"
};
InvokeEndpointResponse invokeResponse = smClient.InvokeEndpoint(invokeRequest);
```

For the moment the `GetImageFromFile` method just reads an image file and transforms it in `MemoryStream`:

```
Stream stream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();

byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(data, 0, (int)stream.Length);
MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream(data);
            
return ms;
```

I tried to serialize the `MemoryStream` by using `Protobuf-net`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert your PNG image into a numpy array (this can be done using [PIL](https://kite.com/python/examples/4887/pil-convert-between-a-pil-%60image%60-and-a-numpy-%60array%60), [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html), or through other libraries).

Once you have the image represented as a ndarray, convert it to protobuf recordIO format as shown in this [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-preprocess-data-transform.html).

Comment: Thank you. This is doable in a Lambda function written in Python, called from the client for instance and processed on the back-end. However, I would like to avoid creating a lambda function and create the protobuf recordIO right from the client in C# to be able to pass it as the argument of the InvokeEndpointRequest.

Comment: The linked example seems to be converting to csv though. Do you have any code to convert into or out of protobuf from within sagemaker?

Comment: @TommyLevi the closest official example I found is in the [parquet_to_recordio_protobuf notebook](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/parquet_to_recordio_protobuf/parquet_to_recordio_protobuf.ipynb).